# Published pages missing

Tags: pages, errors

All my published pages are missing from my wordpress. They are still online on my website (chrisjscambler.com), e.g. I have home, research, and teaching active online; but they are not available to edit in wordpress. They were all there until recently! any suggestions?

Comment: It's not possible to say anything about the circumstances because you are offering no details at all. "They were all there until recently!" is not exactly what a developer should look for. Which version are you using, are there any cleanup plugins installed etc. important things, which you don't provide.

Answer (score 1):

Generally when content is missing it is often related to caching plugins. One of those plugins is OptimizePress which can sometimes conflict and make it seem the content is missing.

Here is what you can try:

- Deactivate all plugins and check again.
- Ensure the server has no caching enabled by asking your hosting
  provider.
- Check to see if your font is not the same color as your background.

If all of that fails, you can ask your hosting provider to see if they have a backup of your site to restore your pages.